# how to compare dates in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, date, comparison

I want compare two dates one would be the current date and other date stored in database. So I want to find out which date is grater from both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check apple [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

You can use the following methods,

- `– isEqualToDate:`
- `– earlierDate:`
- `– laterDate:`
- `– compare:`

Comment: What if I have both dates in string variable?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the compare method of the NSDate class

```
[myDate compare:someOtherDate]
```

This will return one of three values of type NSComparisonResult...

- NSOrderedSame if both dates are equal
- NSOrderedDescending if myDate comes after someOtherDate
- NSOrderedAscending if myDate comes before someOtherDate

Answer (score 0):

You can use `compare:` method to find which date is earlier or later check the documentation on this

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/

Edit:

```
NSDateFormatter * formatter= [NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:stringDate];
[formatter release];
```

then compare them.

Comment: What if I have both dates in string variable?

Comment: you should change them to date first then compare them.